# js slider calls stack doubles after clicking on slider button

Tags: javascript

I have simple js slider that changes div's background color after clicking on previous or next button. It works as expected except that it doubles it calls after every click on button so the window crashes in a short time (i.e. 2, 4, 8, 16, 32). I don't understasnd where the problem is so help would be very appreciated. Here is the link on working [pen](https://codepen.io/MegaZef/pen/XvKQKO) and my code.
HTML code:

```
<div class="skin">
 <div class="prev">
  <i class="flaticon-left-arrow"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-1"></div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-2"></div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-3"></div>
 <div class="next">
  <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
    .skin {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .prev, .next {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #1c2028;
      border-radius: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2068df;
    }

    .skin-color-1 {
      width: 160px;
      height: 80px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: #ffdbb4;
    }

    .skin-color-2 {
      display: none;
      width: 160px;
      height: 80px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: #e2a17f;
    }

    .skin-color-3 {
      display: none;
      width: 160px;
      height: 80px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: #a5673f;
    }
```

And JS:

```
    function slider() {
      let slideIndex = 1,
          skinSlider = document.getElementsByClassName('skin')[0],
          skinSliderItem = document.getElementsByClassName('skin-color'),
          prev = skinSlider.querySelector('.prev'),
          next = skinSlider.querySelector('.next');

      showSlides(slideIndex);

      function showSlides(n) {
        if (n > skinSliderItem.length) {
          slideIndex = 1;
        }
        if (n < 1) {
          slideIndex = skinSliderItem.length;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < skinSliderItem.length; i++) {
          skinSliderItem[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

        skinSliderItem[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';

        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
          plusSlides(-1);
          console.log(skinSliderItem.length);
        });

        next.addEventListener('click', () => {
          plusSlides(1);
          console.log(skinSliderItem.length);
        });
      }
    };

    slider();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a new eventlistener to prev/next div every time you click on it, wich means every time double of the event will fire when clicked.

Move the addEventListener and plusSlides function outside, like this:

```
  function slider() {
      let slideIndex = 1,
          skinSlider = document.getElementsByClassName('skin')[0],
          skinSliderItem = document.getElementsByClassName('skin-color'),
          prev = skinSlider.querySelector('.prev'),
          next = skinSlider.querySelector('.next');

          //... to here:

        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
          plusSlides(-1);
          console.log(skinSliderItem.length);
        });

        next.addEventListener('click', () => {
          plusSlides(1);
          console.log(skinSliderItem.length);
        });

      showSlides(slideIndex);

      function showSlides(n) {
        if (n > skinSliderItem.length) {
          slideIndex = 1;
        }
        if (n < 1) {
          slideIndex = skinSliderItem.length;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < skinSliderItem.length; i++) {
          skinSliderItem[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

        skinSliderItem[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';

        //from here...
      }
    };

    slider();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

your javascript functions are calling itself. That's why it's broken and not responding.

Edit your code like this. Define functions independetly.

```js
  let slideIndex = 1,
      skinSlider = document.getElementsByClassName('skin')[0],
      skinSliderItem = document.getElementsByClassName('skin-color'),
      prev = skinSlider.querySelector('.prev'),
      next = skinSlider.querySelector('.next');

    prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
      plusSlides(-1);
    });

    next.addEventListener('click', () => {
      plusSlides(1);
    });


  function showSlides(n) {
    if (n > skinSliderItem.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = skinSliderItem.length;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < skinSliderItem.length; i++) {
      skinSliderItem[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    skinSliderItem[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
  }

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
```

```css
.skin {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.prev, .next {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1c2028;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2068df;
}

.skin-color-1 {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffdbb4;
}

.skin-color-2 {
  display: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #e2a17f;
}

.skin-color-3 {
  display: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #a5673f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="skin">
    <div class="prev">
     <i class="flaticon-left-arrow"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="skin-color skin-color-1"></div>
    <div class="skin-color skin-color-2"></div>
    <div class="skin-color skin-color-3"></div>
    <div class="next">
     <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for help.